# Help understanding neutral statement vs... er, non-neutral? に　/　には

Tags: grammar, particles

I have two statements in my notes, about a restaurant on the first floor. One is a neutral statement, one is talking about things on the first floor. I am not entirely sure of the context to use them in. Could somebody help please?

> 一階に　レストランが　あります - There is a restaurant on the first floor (neutral statement)
>
> 一階には　レストランが　あります - On the first floor there is a restaurant. (Talking about what is on the first floor).

I think the second example には might be used when discussing the first floor, and perhaps the conversation is about all the shops etc. there. But I am unsure.

Comment: The first floor should be 一階...

Comment: The former sentence tends to be used when the existence of a restaurant is important but its location is not (eg "I'm hungry, what shall we do?"). The latter sentence is natural when you explain what is on each floor (eg "On the first floor, there is ... On the second floor, ..."). But they are often interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for 一階   all these years I've been using the wrong kanji.